# how do I get rid of single quotes around a doubly quoted string in perl? e.g ' "json_text" '

Tags: perl, trim

So I am having a ruby app write json response to the console which is read by another perl program that tries to convert the json response back to a perl hash. Here's my problem:

ruby app outputs the correct json output but the console adds a single quote to it like so:

```
my $ruby_json_out = '"{\"return\":{\"sync_enabled\":false,\"local\":true,\"name\":{\"name\":\"Sam\"}}}"'

my $ret = JSON->new->allow_nonref->decode($ruby_json_out);
```

Now I expect to get hash_ref in $ret but I get a string: `'{"return":{"sync_enabled":false,"local":true,"name":{"name\":"Sam"}}}'`.

I have searched all over the net and can't find a solution to this. When I manually stripout the single quote: 
`"{\"return\":{\"sync_enabled\":false,\"local\":true,\"name\":{\"name\":\"Sam\"}}}"`, 
and run it works.

I am stuck on this for more than a day now and it's driving me crazy. I am new to perl and ruby too so I might be missing something. Any help will be appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you try to solve the problem on the Perl side? Woudln't it be easier to solve it on the Ruby side?
At any rate, you can use regexps to remove those doble quotes in the same way you do it manually:

```
my ($good_json) = ($ruby_json_out =~ /^"(.+?)"$/ ;
```

And then

```
$good_json=~ s/\\"/"/g;
```

Which results in

```
x JSON->new->allow_nonref->decode($good_json) 
0  HASH(0xe4b158)
'return' => HASH(0xe4b1b8)
  'local' => JSON::XS::Boolean=SCALAR(0xd22f00)
     -> 1
  'name' => HASH(0xe4afd8)
     'name' => 'Sam'
  'sync_enabled' => JSON::XS::Boolean=SCALAR(0xd22fd8)
     -> 0
```